# Data passed in the Post request is to big to be passed in single request can we break it into multiple calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm making a call to the server side request ,the data being passed in the request is very large to passed in single request  hence the system breaks in that scenario so what approach should be taken to break down the request data

was not able to come up with anything that would help

```
let postpayloadnew= {
            q: postPayload1.q,
            reportName: this.currentReport.name,
            colDefs: this.currentReport.cols
                .filter(col => {
                    if (this.columnsNeeded == undefined) {
                        return col.selected;
                    } else if (this.columnsNeeded.includes(col.field)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .map(col => ({
                    displayName: col.displayName,
                    field: col.field,
                    cellTemplate: col.cellTemplate
                })),
           results: exportData,
            criteria: this.FilterService.getCriteria(this.currentReport.filters)
        };
```

Client Side

```
this.$http.post(`../api/esr/prep`, postpayloadnew, {
                timeout: this.cancelPDFPromise.promise
            })
            .then(response => {
                window.open(`../api/esr/download/${response.data.fileName}`);
                // this.totalCount = response.data.results.count;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (err.data) {
                    swal({
                        text: "Failed to download file!",
                    });
                }
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.loadingPDF = false;
            });
    }
```

Server Side

```
 server.route({
        path: '/api/esr/prep',
        method: 'POST',
        handler(req, reply) {  Logic here} });
```

Comment: You might need to divide payload into chunks, here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878059/overcome-hosts-max-file-size-limit-for-php-post-data-when-uploading-files

Comment: he is trying to send multiple files ,I have a single data that exceeds the length of the post request allowed.

Comment: Not really, he needs to upload a 100MB file when the limit is 32MB. Answers say to split the file into chunks, send every chunk and then reconstruct everything server-side.

Comment: even of you're posting strings, same concept applies: split it into chunks

Comment: ya ,but is there anyway to reconstruct everything on server side javascript any head start in that direction would be appreciated